# How to compare two Ratios of Rectangles / Sizes to determine their percentages of differences?

Tags: math, discrete-mathematics

I have a ractangle whose ratio is 80:40 and other rectangles with similar aspect ratios within a humbral for example 80:35, 85:45, that unbral is a decimal or integer.

My problem is that I need to compare other rectangles with the first one and determine a difference in their respective aspect ratios in percentages, for example: 80:30 is 20% different in aspect ratio than 80:40.

(20% is not a calculated data, it is an example idea, because I don't know how to do it).

Could it be that a totally opposite aspect ratio is 100% different? For example: 80:40 is 100% different than 40:80

Imagine that you have a collection of rectangles and a target rectangle and you have to filter the collection leaving only those rectangles that have an aspect ratio similar to the target rectangle.

**Sample:**

```
private float GetDiffRatio(FloatSize size1, FloatSize size2) {
    float fixedR1 = size1.Width / size1.Height;
    if (fixedR1 >= 0)
        // Invert and negative.
        fixedR1 = -(size1.Height / size1.Width);

    float fixedR2 = size2.Width / size2.Height;
    if (fixedR2 >= 0)
        // Invert and negative.
        fixedR2 = -(size2.Height / size1.Width);

    float rDiff = fixedR1 - fixedR2;
    return rDiff * 100f;
}
```

**Test:**

```
float diffRatio = GetDiffRatio(new FloatSize(100f, 50f), new FloatSize(50f, 100f));
```

**Results** = -100f

**Test2 (inverted order of parameters):**

```
float diffRatio = GetDiffRatio(new FloatSize(50f, 100f), new FloatSize(100f, 50f));
```

**Results** = 100f

I am not sure that this is a valid or correct form, I do not know if it can generate any condition that returns a wrong percentage of similarity.

Comment: I edited the question and placed an example.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question depends a lot on what exactly you're trying to do or you're planning to uses this similarity function for. I find it very unintuitive to say that opposite aspect ratio leads to 0% similarity. I think comparing two rectangles r1=(2.1,2) and r2=(2,2.1) should be a lot more similar to each other then for example r3=(1,5) r4=(5,1).
This is not me saying that it couldn't be useful in some case to have a similarity function like your's, I just want to explain that it depends a lot on what you're doing ...

I would say a very obvious solution would be to just divide width by height of every rectangle and take as similarity-function s1 the absolute value from both values subtracted. So for my provided examples the result would be:

s1(r1,r2) = | 2.1/2 - 2/2.1 | = 0.0976...

s1(r2,r3) = | 1/5 - 5/1 | = 4.8

If it is also important that you have values between 0 and 1 you could additionally plug this values in for example this function ...

[image]

where

[image]

b must be smaller than 0 and is a parameter with what you can controll how fast the funciton converges to 1. YOu can play around with it here: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/nwlq3ujouq

In the case you really want something as you suggested, i would simply do the following:

You take your constraint that every rectangle is between the ratio a:b and c:d. Than you calculate x1=a/b and x2=c/d and then you interpolate the value from zero to one between those values so:

h(x1) = 0

h(x2) = 1

if you need more details on how to do this look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation but i think it's very straight forward.

The similarity function s3 can then be build again with the absolute value of the difference

s3=| h(r1)-h(r2) |